# Is my proof of density of rational numbers in the reals correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a,b$ are real numbers such that $a < b$.

By Archimedeans' Property, there exists natural number $n$ such that $n(b-a) > 1$.

Then $na < na + 1 < nb$.

Note $n|a| + 1 >0$.

Applying the Archimedeans' Principle, we get $ an+1 \leq n |a| + 1 < m_0 $ for some natural $m_0$

Let $S$ be the set of all naturals $M$ such that $an + 1 < M$.

Then $S$ is nonempty and bounded above, so it has least upper bound $m$.

Note $nb$ is an upper-bound of set $S$, so $ m \leq nb $.

Then $ na < na + 1 < m \leq nb $

Subtracting by $1$, we obtain

$$ na < m-1 < m \leq nb $$

Division by $n$ gives the desired result $$ a < \frac{m-1}{n} < b$$

QED

Comment: Why do think $\ nb\ $ is an upper bound of $\ S\ $?  I think you really want $\ M\ $ to be the *greatest lower bound* of $\ S\ $, which is bounded below (by $\ an+1\ $), but not (as far as I can see) bounded above.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

$$S = \{ M \in \mathbb{N}: an+1 < M \}$$ is not bounded above, I think you intend to define it differently.